# How can I implement a repetitive promise call chain?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

*Please know I'm not looking for the reduce pattern which assumes I already need to know the number of executions beforehand. Recursivity here is also overkill.*

I need to execute a call that returns a Promise (either resolved / rejected) in a row until, in that Promise's return data I find a certain keyword, pseudo-code:

```
let response_that_will_come_from_each_promise = null;

do {
    response_that_will_come_from_each_promise = execute_my_call_that_is_a_promise();
} while(!('finished_all_calls' in response_that_will_come_from_each_promise ));
```

Unfortunately, this won't work with the asynchronous nature of promises. A for loop won't also do because both `do` and `for` are synchronous.

In short, how can I keep calling the same function that also happens to return a promise for N times until I detect that something is wrong?

Comment: possibly look into an async generator? https://jakearchibald.com/2017/async-iterators-and-generators/

Comment: @BrianGlaz That looks neat and is part of the solution, but again, my issue is with actually doing these N calls over and over. This is the "after" problem you're talking about. I have no idea how to write the code to keep calling that fetch.

Comment: that's what the generator does for you. Like in the example on that page you can do `for await(const promiseVal of promiseGenerator()) { if(promiseVal === 'finished_all_calls') { break; } else { //do stuff } })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer:

For re-usability and maintenance you could create a constructor function that does this for you:

```
function PromiseUntil(promiseFn, conditional) {
let trace = (place) => e => console.log(`trace: ${place} :: ${e}`);
  return {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]: async function*() {
      let p;
      while(p != conditional) {  p = await promiseFn().catch(trace("PromiseUntil[Symbol.asyncIterator]")) }
      yield p;
    },
    resolve: async function(cb = i => i, err = trace("PromiseUntil.resolve")) {
    this.resolve = false;
      try {
        for await (let p of this) {
            this.resolved = true;
            return cb(p);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        err(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It simply takes a promise function and repeats it until the value returned by the resolved Promise matches the conditional. In the below it checks if it equals `"awaited value"`. Once it matches, it is returned, and the callback function ( in the example `console.log` ) is called with that value.

---

### Example:

```js
function PromiseUntil(promiseFn, conditional) {
let trace = (place) => e => console.log(`trace: ${place} :: ${e}`);
  return {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]: async function*() {
      let p;
      while(p != conditional) {  p = await promiseFn().catch(trace("PromiseUntil[Symbol.asyncIterator]")) }
      yield p;
    },
    resolve: async function(cb = i => i, err = trace("PromiseUntil.resolve")) {
    this.resolve = false;
      try {
        for await (let p of this) {
            this.resolved = true;
            return cb(p);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        err(e);
      }
    }
  }
}


let a = () => new Promise(res => (Math.random() >= 0.5) ? (console.log("no"), res("not awaited value")) : (console.log("yes"), res("awaited value")));

let waiter = PromiseUntil(a, "awaited value");
waiter.resolve(console.log);
```

---

### Adjusted For Conditional Function:

After thinking over the above answer, it would probably be best if you could pass in a conditional **function** and not just a primitive value to match. That way you could check against an object property or whatever comparison you'd like, etc.

This adjustment changes the parameter name from `conditional` to `conditionalFn` and adjusts the while loop from:

```
while(p != conditional)
```

to:

```
while(p == undefined || !conditionalFn(p))
```

---

### Example:

In the below we have two constructed `PromiseUntil` Objects.

- The first is assigned a promise function that will resolve when the returned `string` includes `"fin"`.
- The second is assigned a promise function that will resolve when the returned `object` (*a user object in this case*) has an `id` property of `1`

```js
function PromiseUntil(promiseFn, conditionalFn) {
let trace = (place) => e => console.log(`trace: ${place} :: ${e}`);
  return {
    [Symbol.asyncIterator]: async function*() {
      let p;
      while(p == undefined || !conditionalFn(p)) {  
        p = await promiseFn().catch(trace("PromiseUntil[Symbol.asyncIterator]")) 
      }
      yield p;
    },
    resolve: async function(cb = i => i, err = trace("PromiseUntil.resolve")) {
    this.resolve = false;
      try {
        for await (let p of this) {
            this.resolved = true;
            return cb(p);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        err(e);
      }
    }
  }
}



let a = () => new Promise(res => (Math.random() >= 0.5) ? (console.log("First Example: no"), res("not awaited value")) : (console.log("First Example: yes"), res("First Example: finished"))),

b = () => new Promise(res => (Math.random() >= 0.5) ? (console.log("Second Example: no"), res({ id: 2 })) : (console.log("Second Example: yes"), res({id: 1, name: "John Smith" })) );

let waiter = PromiseUntil(a, val => val.includes("fin"));
waiter.resolve(console.log);

let waiter_two = PromiseUntil(b, user => user.id == 1);
waiter_two.resolve(user => console.log(`Second Example: Found User: ${user.id} , ${user.name}`));
```

---

### Aside: Infinite looping

In the above code the PromiseUntil Objects will continue to try and resolve their Promise Functions indefinitely. If the conditional is never met this can cause infinite recursion. To avoid this you can set either a maximum duration to try and resolve for the condition, or a number of attempts. The below demonstrates how to do so:

```js
function PromiseUntil( promiseFn, conditionalFn, {maxDuration, maxAttempts} = {} ) {
  let trace = ( place ) => e => console.log( `trace: ${place} :: ${e}` ),
    timeout = ( reason ) => trace( "PromiseUntil Time Out" )( Error( reason ) ),
    limit = max => current => ( max && max <= current );

  return {
    promiseName: promiseFn.name,
    [ Symbol.asyncIterator ]: async function*() {
      const exceeds = {
        duration: limit( Date.now() + maxDuration ),
        attempts: limit( maxAttempts )
      };
      let attempts = 0;

      let p;
      while ( p == undefined || !conditionalFn( p ) ) {
        if ( exceeds.duration( Date.now() ) ) throw timeout( `${this.promiseName} Max Duration Met` );
        if ( exceeds.attempts( attempts++ ) ) throw timeout( `${this.promiseName} Max Resolution Attempts` );

        p = await promiseFn().catch( trace( "PromiseUntil[Symbol.asyncIterator]" ) );
      }
      yield p;
    },
    resolve: async function( cb = i => i, err = trace( "PromiseUntil.resolve" ) ) {
      this.resolve = false;
      try {
        for await ( let p of this ) {
          this.resolved = true;
          return cb( p );
        }
      }
      catch ( e ) {
        if ( e ) err( e );
      }
    }
  }
}


// our promise functions
let delayedPromise = () => new Promise( res =>
    setTimeout( () => Math.random() >= 0.5 ? res( "not awaited value" ) : res( "delayedPromise Successful: finished" ), 500 ) ),
 
  attemptPromise = () => new Promise( res => 
          Math.random() >= 0.5 ? res( {id: 2} ) : res( {id: 1, name: "John Smith" } ) );


// our PromiseUntil Objects
let wait_for_fin = PromiseUntil( delayedPromise, val => val.includes( "fin" ), {
    maxDuration: 300
  } ),
 
  wait_for_user_one = PromiseUntil( attemptPromise, user => user.id == 1, {
    maxAttempts: 2
  } );

// our Resolvers
wait_for_fin.resolve( console.log );
wait_for_user_one.resolve( user => console.log( `attemptPromise Successful: Found User: ${user.id} , ${user.name}` ) );
```

Comment: You know that there is `Symbol.asyncIterator` ?

Comment: And why having that iterator at all, if it `yield`s only once? I also don't understand why you have to keep that array of functions?

Comment: @JonasWilms I appreciate the input, this is admittedly a bit worse for wear. I'll adjust it to be a bit more compact - but no I wasn't aware of `asyncIterator`, or at least it's not on my mind as often as `iterator`. I can't imagine there's that much difference, but give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 4):

`while` can be async inside an `async function`:

```
  async function pollStuff() {
    while(!("keyword" in await somePromise());
  }
```

Without async / await recursion is your friend:

```
 const pollStuff = () => 
   somePromise().then(result => "keyword" in result ? "done" : pollStuff())
```

Comment: You again! Thanks for giving me hope in `async` again. I get that the `while` waits for my `somePromise()` to end its chain but, uh, that's exactly my problem. How do I create that chain as per my specs? I can use `await`, that's fine now since I had no issues with the polyfills but I don't know how to do the "await recursion".

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently moving to another city and all my stuff is already there, that's why I'm currently really bored and the only thing I can do on my phone is playing some games or answering on SO :)